# C++ Debug Assertion Failed in vector

Tags: c++, memory-corruption

I encountered an assertion failed in visual studio 2013. I write a class named Image and I would like to create a vector of Image, but a "Ddebug Assertion Failed" happened.

Here is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Image {
public:
    Image() : dataptr(nullptr)
    {}

    Image(int s) : rows(s), cols(s), dataptr(nullptr)
    {
        dataptr = new T[s * s];
    }
    Image(int r, int c) : rows(r), cols(c), dataptr(nullptr)
    {
        dataptr = new T[rows * cols];
    }
    ~Image()
    {
        if (dataptr != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] dataptr;
            dataptr = nullptr;
        }
    }

    T* const operator[] (int i)
    {
        return &dataptr[i*cols];
    }

private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    T* dataptr;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Image<int> img(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            img[i][j] = i * 3 + j;
        }
    }

    vector<Image<int>> ims(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ims.push_back(img);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the error :
[image]
[image]
I know it is caused by a memory corruption, but I can't find out where it happens.

Comment: This error disappeared when I cancel the destructor, what's wrong with it ?

Comment: I would look this suspicious guy very closely : T* const operator[] (int i)

Comment: Look at your `operator[]`.  Ask yourself what is the type of `dataptr[i*cols]`

Comment: Oddly I think img[i][j] actually works ok (in the symmetric case at least

Comment: @virgesmith `img[i][j]` is only valid if `j` is `0`.  If it is not 0 then it is UB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom copy and assignment for your Image class. The compiler-generated ones are shallow-copied so you're getting double deletes when you copy objects into a vector, and the vector is subsequently destructed. You need a deep copy, or a shared_pointer.

Adding this fixes:

```
Image(const Image& i) : rows(i.rows), cols(i.cols)
{
  dataptr = new T[rows*cols];
  // now actually copy the data... 
}
```